# How to run Python 3 when I type "python" in windows CMD

Tags: windows, python-3.x, variables, cmd, path

I'm wondering how I could run python3 by default when I type `python` in windows CMD?

This is not a duplicated question because I've added the C:\Python36 to the path variables, so when I type `py` in CMD, it gives me `python 3.6.2`, while if I type `py2`, then it gives me `python 2.7.11`.

Since now I need to run `python script.py` through another application, then I can't really change the command to be `py script.py`, so my question is how could I run python 3  if using the command `python script.py`? I've tried to place the python3 preceeding python2 like `C:\Python36;C:\Python27` in the variables, but when I type `python`, CMD still shows `python 2.7.11`...I'm confused about why it didn't work..

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK! I figured out the issue - The python36 folder was not placed in the C: location. Now I've corrected it and it's working for me! Thanks!